# Cannot start Nexus 9 screen mirroring to Viera TV

Tags: dlna, screencast, miracast, screen-mirroring

Nexus 9 currently runs Android 6.0.1 (MMB29S) with ElementalX kernel 4.05 and Chainfire's SuperSU 2.66 (if that matters); on the TV side, - it is Panasonic Viera TX-42CSR610 and it has screen mirroring function. WiFi direct finds the device, I am also able to send videos with sound from Nexus to it (as well as from a Windows 10 pc). However if I start the "Cast screen" from Nexus, it says "No devices available"; also when I invoke screen mirroring app on the TV, WiFi direct loses it.

I've tried about dozen playstore apps with no avail, including Chromecast, Mirror beta, Wifi display, Wireless display (Miracast) and others, all of them failed in different ways.

Presumably it will work with additional hardware like Chromecast, what I want to know is whether it is supposed to work as is, and if yes, why does not it work.

I found some similar questions here, they are about some different hardware/software combinations. Is there a known common problem?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it thanks to [this](http://graesen.com/2015/03/how-i-got-wireless-display-miracast-to-work-on-my-nexus-6/): after adding `persist.debug.wfd.enable=1` to `build.prop` the option to enable wireless display appeared in cast screen options. It took several attempts to connect and I don't really know what did it work after all, but it works now.

One drawback remains though - when mirroring display I don't have access to the wireless router, so I cannot display any new content from, say, facebook, only the stuff that was cached beforehand. But this is obviously the matter of a different question.